# Scrapy recursive crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like crawl some websites.
The problem is that I can't crawl the next pages

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

import urlparse 
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MySpider(Spider):
name = "craig"
allowed_domains = ["mmoga.de"]
start_urls = ["https://www.mmoga.de/BattleNet-Games/",
              "https://www.mmoga.de/EA-Games/",
              "https://www.mmoga.de/Gamecards-CD-Keys/",
              "https://www.mmoga.de/Steam-Games/"]


rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("Seite-\d00", ),restrict_xpaths=('//a',))
, callback="parse", follow= True),
)
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)

    ne = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    next_page = ne.select("//td[@class='pagerNextlink']/a/@href").extract()

    titles  = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tr')
    section = hxs.select('//div[@id="productListFilterContainer"]')
    items   = []
    for title in titles:
        item             = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item ["section"] = section.select('div/h2/text()').extract()
        item ["preis"]   = title.xpath('td/div[@style="margin-bottom:5px;"]/text()').extract()

        if not item ["preis"]:
           item ["preis"] = title.xpath('td/div[@style="margin-bottom:5px;color:#F00;"]/text()').extract()

        item ["title"]   = title.xpath("td/a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"]    = title.xpath('td/a/@href').extract()


        if not item ["preis"]:
           pass
        else:
           items.append(item)
    return items
```

The next pages are in this format: `.../Seite-1`

https://www.mmoga.de/Steam-Games/Seite-1

This program runs without error in the terminal:

```
scrapy crawl craig -o item.csv
```

Comment: If I run the command line you say works for you (`scrapy crawl craig -o item.csv`), `scrapy` tells me I'm using an unknown command: `crawl`. Can you show a command that will work outside of your environment?

Comment: Do you have install scrapy?

Comment: Scrapy is a python framework